# What is the default redirect code in lighttpd's mod_redirect? 301 or 302?

Tags: http, redirect, lighttpd

What is the default redirect code in lighttpd's mod_redirect? HTTP Status 301 (moved permanently) or 302 (found / temporarily moved)?

Comment: I know url.redirect-code was added in 1.5.0.  Just want to know the default redirect code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.  I found the answer: 301 redirect, as I had expected.

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository/revisions/1580/diff/trunk/src/mod_redirect.c (line 195)